# Bootstrap nav-tabs function not working in 4.6 version under asp webform situation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4.6 version and try to use nav function to create nav-link tabs,
however, when I click another tab in screen, it not working.
The code snippets is as following:

```
<head runat="server">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../JavaScript/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JavaScript/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("../Css/bootstrap.min.css");
        @import url("../Css/style.css");
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li>
                <div class="nav-link" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="personal">AAA</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="employment">BBB</div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="personal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
                TESTING AAA
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="employment" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                TESTING BBB
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to solve this question.
It seems like a conflict between jquery 3.5.1 and bootstrap, could there exist any way to
solve that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<li class="nav-item">` instead, and then it can work very well.